# How to correctly create a Writer object that write a .txt file into a Java application?

Tags: java, file

I have the following problem trying to create a **Writer** object (that have to create a **.txt** file) into a Java application. So I am trying to create it in this way:

```
private Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("thefile.txt"));
```

The problem is that Eclipe give me the following syntax errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The value of the field DatiPianiInterventiRowCallbackHandler.writer is not used
    - Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit 
     constructor
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and correctly create a new **Writer** object to write my textual file?

Comment: "The value of the field DatiPianiInterventiRowCallbackHandler.writer is not used" is not an error but a warning. Apparently you never use the writer you created, which is almost never what you actually want.

Comment: What do you mean by writing **into** a Java application?

Comment: The messages from Eclipse are clear enough. What do you not understand about them?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the Writer properly, but not in the right place, from your errors. You seem to be creating it as the member of a class, it should be created (and closed) inside a method. As a member of a class, this code can throw an IOException, which is what's causing your second error (the first is only a warning that you don't do anything with writer).

```
 public void doWrite() throws IOException {
     Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("thefile.txt"));
     // do writes...
     writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileWriter constructor throws a checked exception. You should instantiate the object in a method and use a try catch block or specify that your method throws the same exception.

```
private Writer writer;
```

Then in a method you do

```
writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("thefile.txt"));
```

But again, it must be surrounded with a try-catch or your method must declare the same exception. This is the rule for handling checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`private Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("thefile.txt"));`

is pretty much equivalent to

```
private Writer writer;

public MyClass() throws IOException {
    super();
    this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("thefile.txt"));
}
```

Except the latter does work because it correctly declares the checked exception.